# Android ICS Unlock Screen - View

Tags: android, view, locking, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I would like to know if there is a view I could use which seems like the unlock circle view in ICS ( Android 4.0 )

Thanks

Comment: No, there isn't. You have to make one. :)

Comment: Search for "joystick" algorithm, use it add additional functions

Comment: I'm still searching for a component (not algorithm only) Thank you Pleerock, your answer is interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For developers who are looking for an answer to this question :

[GlowPad library](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sebastianopoggi.samples.ui.GlowPadSample)